# Spring Security not working properly in my spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am using spring security with JWT token in my spring boot application and I am trying to use spring security related features(like isauthenticated,hasRole,hasAuthority,etc) in my jsp page but they are not working. Facing same issue in my controller whereas In RESTController, They works fine with @preauthorize tag.

pom.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bdtool</groupId>
    <artifactId>BD-Tool</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>BD-Tool</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency> 
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
      </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my config class:-

```
package com.bdtool.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "jwtUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index", "/resources/**", "/JS/**", "/register", "/authenticate", "/login",
                "/signout", "/signup", "/forgotPassword", "/submitSignupDetails")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtRequestFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtRequestFilter();
    }

}
```

Here is my JwtRequestFilter

```
package com.bdtool.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.bdtool.service.JwtTokenBeanService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;


@Component
@JsonSerialize
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService JwtUserDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenBeanService jwtTokenBeanService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ") ) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);

                try {
                     
                    username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                    
                    System.out.println("From jwt req filter:-"+username);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    throw new ServletException("Unable to get JWT Token");
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    throw new ServletException("JWT Token has expired");
                }
    
        
        } else {

        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.JwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here is JwttokenUtil

```
package com.bdtool.config;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;



@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 60 * 60;
    
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

Userdetailservice class:-

```
package com.bdtool.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bdtool.bean.Users;
import com.bdtool.dao.UsersDao;



@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService  implements UserDetailsService {
    

    
    @Autowired
    private UsersDao userdao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    
        Users user=userdao.findUserData(username);
        
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authrole = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>() ;

        authrole.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getUserType()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, user.getUserPassword(),
                authrole);
        

    }
    

    
}
```

AuthenticateController :-

```
package com.bdtool.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bdtool.bean.Users;
import com.bdtool.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.bdtool.config.JwtUserDetailsService;
import com.bdtool.dao.UsersDao;
import com.bdtool.model.JwtRequest;
import com.bdtool.model.JwtResponse;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthenticateController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(JwtRequest jwtRequest) {
        try {
        
             
            authenticate(jwtRequest.getUsername(), jwtRequest.getPassword());
            final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(jwtRequest.getUsername());
            final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Invalid Credentials", e);
        }
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint:-

```
package com.bdtool.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
    
}
```

AJAX->

```
$("#somebutton").click(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'logout',
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("Token")
                },
                success: function() {
                    console.log("ok");
                }
            });
        });
```

My JSP code:-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
    uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>


    class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">

                            <li><a href="adminProjectDashboard">Project Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="adminProductDashboard">Product Dashboard</a></li>

                        </sec:authorize>

                    </ul></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seams over-complicated to me. I have a sample resource-server retrieving authorities from a JPA repo [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken-jpa-authorities) and web security config is no more complicated than:

```java
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor expressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor() {
            return (ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry) -> registry
                    .antMatchers("/secured-route")
                    .hasRole("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
        }

        @Bean
        public SynchronizedJwt2AuthenticationConverter<JwtAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter(
                ClaimSet2AuthoritiesConverter<ClaimSet> authoritiesConverter) {
            return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(new UnmodifiableClaimSet(jwt.getClaims())));
        }

        @Bean
        public ClaimSet2AuthoritiesConverter<ClaimSet> authoritiesConverter(UserAuthorityRepository authoritiesRepo) {
            return new PersistedGrantedAuthoritiesRetriever(authoritiesRepo);
        }
    }
```

It makes usage of a few @ConditionalOnMissingBean auto-configured by spring-boot, but you can find the list [in source](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/ServletSecurityBeans.java) (and they are not so many).

### PS

A way more efficient approach is adding authorities to JWT access-tokens (inside authorization-server): SQL request is executed only when a new token is emitted, not at each request.

It is easy to map authorities from JWT private claims.

### Other PS

The Java version you are using is very deprecated and Spring versions comming this fall will require Java 17 as minimum

### Last PS

your boot version is deprecated too and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should not be used anymore, in favor of [providing a `SecurityFiterChain` @Bean](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/d323b05183b472560fd6a05246ecfbf99912ee9f/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/ServletSecurityBeans.java#L121) (this already works in the boot version you use)

Comment: Thanks...After changing the version ,authorized/authenticated request works perfectly in PostMan but for same request browser shows Unauthorized 401..!